# How can I match a string when not preceded by a digit using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file where the 2nd column looks like this:

```
37M533N38M
14M1170N45M233N16M
3S45M3N35M
```

I want to extract those strings which contain `3N` *but* no other numbers immediately before the `3`. So, for example, `A3N` would match but `23N` would not. It should also be noted that `3N` would never be present alone and the string will not start with `3N` and will not end with `3N`.
The result should be the third line from the above:

```
3S45M3N35M
```

How can I do it in awk? I have tried `$2 ~ /3N/` but that certainly doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a negated character class: `[^0-9]` means "any character except a digit":

```
awk '$2~/[^0-9]3N/' file
```

If you also want to match cases where the `3N` is at the very beginning of the field so there are no characters before it, use:

```
awk '$2~/(^|[^0-9])3N/' file
```

If you only want to print the second field and not the whole line, use:

```
awk '$2~/[^0-9]3N/{print $2}' file
```

or

```
awk '$2~/(^|[^0-9])3N/{print $2}' file
```

Comment: For the second case you describe, you could also just use: `awk '($2 ~ /3N/) && ($2 !~ /[0-9]3N/)'`

Comment: @Wildcard why would I want to use two tests where one would do?

Comment: You wouldn't.  But I thought it worth noting in the comments for pedagogical simplicity.

Comment: Why do you put a ``+`` after the `[^0-9]`?

Comment: @G-Man Um, because I had originally used `*` which is of course wrong, and just changed it to `+` without realizing I didn't actually need anything at all. In my defense, it's late here.

Answer (score 0):

**Using grep:**

```
grep [^0-9][3][N] file
```

> **v** - to show those that don't match / invert match
>
> **[0-9][3][N]** - pattern to find 3N with a positive integer preceding.

Comment: Why the `[3]`? There's not much point in using a character class for a single character. Also, you could do this in one go with `grep -E '[^0-9]+3N' file`.

Comment: Yes, agree. That is a better approach for sure.

Comment: @terdon Well, yes he could, but he forgets to match only in the second column.

Comment: @Kusalananda ah yes, true. I guess you could do something like `grep -E '^\S+\s+\S+[^0-9]+3N' file` then. Or, to get only the second field (and assuming GNU grep): `grep -Po '^\S+\s+\K\S+[^0-9]+3N\S+' file`.

Comment: @terdon: Even that approach won't work correctly (it might pick up the third, fourth, fifth, or ... etc., column) unless you anchor it with `^`.

Comment: @G-Man indeed. Comment edited (one of the perks of being a mod).

Comment: In shells other than `fish`, `[^0-9][3][N]` is a glob, so if there one or more file names matching that pattern in the current directory, they will be expanded by the shell, and if there's no matching file, in shells like csh, tcsh or zsh, you'd get an error message. You'd want to quote that argument to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below command  and it worked fine for above example

```
awk '$2 ~ /[A-Za-z]3N/{print $0}' filename
```